# Ensuring packet order in UDP

Tags: windows, udp, winsock, packet

I'm using 2 computers with an application to send and receive udp datagrams. There is no flow control and ICMP is disabled. Frequently when I send a file as UDP datagrams via the application, I get two packets changing their order and therefore - packet loss.

I've disabled and kind of firewall and there is no hardware switch connected between the computers (they are directly wired).

Is there a way to make sure Winsock and `send()` will send the packets the same way they got there?

Or is the OS doing that?

Or network device configuration needed?

Comment: In a point-to-point connection I would expect the packets to be in order, that's an assumption that proved 100% right with my experience with embedded systems. Could it be Receive Side Scaling causing what you see?

Answer (score 15):

UDP is a lightweight protocol that by design doesn't handle things like packet sequencing. TCP is a better choice if you want robust packet delivery and sequencing.

UDP is generally designed for applications where packet loss is acceptable or preferable to the delay which TCP incurs when it has to re-request packets. UDP is therefore commonly used for media streaming.

If you're limited to using UDP you would have to develop a method of identifying the out of sequence packets and resequencing them.

Answer (score 9):

UDP does not guarantee that your packets will arrive in order. (It does not even guarantee that your packets will arrive at all.) If you need that level of robustness you are better off with TCP. Alternatively you could add sequence markers to your datagrams and rearrange them at the other end, but why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: from a praticular reason i cant describe im limited to udp only. a rare packetloss once and then is accaptable. it just that 1 of 3 files gets a loss. i just need to find a way for the sender to send the packets in the right order, the rest doesnt matter for me. thanks

Comment: It's not so much a question of the sender sending the packets in the right order as for the receiver to reassemble them into the correct order. Like I said, add sequence markers at some appropriate level.

Comment: UDP does guarantee that a packet will arrive intact or not at all (i.e., it has a checksum) and it also adds port numbers to raw IP. It doesn't guarantee delivery or sequencing; those are what TCP adds (by basically shouting out a packet until the other end says that it has arrived). Guaranteed correct in-order delivery is also enough that you can pretend you've got a stream of data (hence TCP is a streaming socket, since that's pretty commonly desired).

Answer (score 7):

> is there a way to make sure winsock and send() will send the packets the same way they got there?

It's called TCP.

Alternatively try a reliable UDP protocol such as [UDT](http://udt.sourceforge.net/).  I'm guessing you might be on a small embedded platform so you want a more compact protocol like Bell Lab's [RUDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliable_User_Datagram_Protocol).

Answer (score 0):

> there is no flow control (ICMP disabled)

You can implement your own flow control using UDP:

- Send one or more UDP packets
- Wait for acknowledgement (sent as another UDP packets from receiver to sender)
- Repeat as above

See [Sliding window protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_window_protocol) for further details.

[This would be **in addition to** having a sequence number in the packets which you send.]

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in trying to create your own TCP like wrapper. We love the speed of UPD and that is just going to slow things down. Your problem can be overcome if you design your protocol so that every UDP datagram is independent of each other. Our packets can arrive in any order so long as the header packet arrives first. The header says how many packets are suppose to arrive. Also, UPD has become a lot more reliable since this post was created over a decade ago. Don't try to

Answer (score 0):

This question is 12 years old, and it seems almost a waste to answer it now.  Even as the suggestions that I have have already been posed.  I dealt with this issue back in 2002, in a program that was using UDP broadcasts to communicate with other running instances on the network.  If a packet got lost, it wasn't a big deal.  But if I had to send a large packet, greater than 1020 bytes, I broke it up into multiple packets.  Each packet contained a header that described what packet number it was, along with a header that told me it was part of a larger overall packet.  So, the structure was created, and the payload was simply dropped in the (correct) place in the buffer, and the bytes were subtracted from the overall total that was needed.  I knew all the packets had arrived once the *needed* byte total reached zero.  Once all of the packets arrived, that packet got processed.  If another advertisement packet came in, then everything that had been building up was thrown away.  That told me that one of the fragments didn't make it.  But again, this wasn't critical data; the code could live without it.  But, I did implement an `AdvReplyType` in every packet, so that if it **was** a critical packet, I could reply to the sender with an `ADVERTISE_INCOMPLETE_REQUEST_RETRY` packet type, and the whole process could start over again.

This whole system was designed for LAN operation, and in all of my debugging/beta testing, I rarely ever lost a packet, but on larger networks I would often get them out of order...but I did get them.  Being that it's now 12 years later, and UDP broadcasting seems to be frowned upon by a lot of IT Admins, UDP doesn't seem like a good, solid system any longer.  [ChrisW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/49942/chrisw) mentioned a Sliding Window Protocol; this is sort of what I built...without the sliding part!  More of a "Fixed Window Protocol".  I just wasted a few more bytes in the header of each of the payload packets to tell how many total bytes are in this Overlapped Packet, which packet this was, and the unique MsgID it belonged to so that I didn't have to get the initial packet telling me how many packets to expect.  Naturally, I didn't go as far as implementing [RFC 1982](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1982), as that seemed like overkill for this.  As long as I got one packet, I'd know the total length, unique Message Id, and which packet number this one was, making it pretty easy to `malloc()` a buffer large enough to hold the entire Message.  Then, a little math could tell me where exactly in the Message this packet fits into.  Once the Message buffer was filled in...I knew I got the whole message.  If a packet arrived that didn't belong to this unique Message ID, then we knew this was a bust, and we likely weren't going to ever get the remainder of the old message.

The only real reason I mention this today, is that I believe there still is a time and a place to use a protocol like this.  Where TCP actually involves too much overhead, on slow, or spotty networks; but it's those where you also have the most likelihood of and possible fear of packet loss.  So, again, I'd also say that "reliability" cannot be a requirement, or you're just right back to TCP.  If I had to write this code today, I probably would have just implemented a Multicast system, and the whole process probably would have been a lot easier on me.  Maybe.  It *has* been 12 years, and I've probably forgotten a huge portion of the implementation details.

Sorry, if I woke a sleeping giant here, that wasn't my intention.  The original question intrigued me, and reminded me of this turn-of-the-century Windows C++ code I had written.  So, please try to keep the negative comments to a minimum--if at all possible!  (Positive comments, of course...*always* welcome!) J/K, of course, folks.