# Only 16 UDP 512 byte packets being received by server when I sent 7mb total

Tags: java, network-programming, udp, packet

I break a 7mb file into 512b chunks and I send it with udp to a server. About 14000 packets get sent by the client but on the server side socket.receive(packet) blocks after receiving only 16 packets.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: A network device in between discards them.

Comment: @nos: Edited my post to say 512 bytes. I am sending the packets to localhost so why is my machine dropping everything after the first 16 packets?

Comment: 1. post your code. 2. add a sleep(100) on emitter side to slow down (for testing purpose only)

Comment: I added a 3ms sleep and all the packets are getting through now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UDP is defined as an unreliable protocol. Packets may be lost, and without the sender being informed. They may also arrive out of order and even duplicates may arrive.

UDP is suitable for purposes where error checking and correction is either unnecessary, or is performed by the application itself.

If you want a reliable protocol, start using TCP.

Comment: I know how UDP and TCP work, I am using UDP as a learning exercise. Packets may be lost alright but why are only the first 16 packets out of 1400+ getting sent. Every single time only the first 16 packets arrive at the server.

Comment: @csss If you throw a bunch of packets at full speed towards a machine, and the server program doesn't react and read them quickly enough the socket queue will fill up (all that's needed is for the OS to decide to schedule some other process for a few moments to fill up a socket queue) and subsequent packets get dropped. i.e. you need flow control, which UDP does not give you. There could ofcourse also be a bug in your client and/or server

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to TCP, UDP does neither ensure packet order nor actual delivery (no flow control as in TCP). See this question: [ensuring packet order in UDP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3745115/1175253)

Comment: note that flow control is not the same as (guaranteed) delivery.

Comment: It is not the same. But without the basic mechanisms of flow control, also a NACK message, based on sequence numbers, cannot be sent back for sure. Another algorithm to handle losses and out of order issues must be implemented, which is probably not worth the effort for just transmitting a file in unicast, where TCP may be the right choice.